# SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I want to use SQL Server 2005 as database.In know how to create table in SQL server 2005.But due to fault i reinstalled SQL Server 2005.After that i create table as follows

```
start -> programs -> microsoft sql server 2005 -> sql server management studio express
```

But in that "Sql server management studio express" not exit,How to display that option please guide than only i do further

Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you mean "exist", not "exit".

Answer (score 2):

You need to download and install [Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en).

You can use either the 2005 or 2008 version of Management Studio to connect to a SQL Server 2005 database.